# How to see mt_rand physically in php

Tags: php

Hello this is my first php code. :D
The question is how can I see each number trand which trand has generated? 
I don't need a new code. I want to think for myself.
What methods can I use to physically see the generated code?

`````
function trand(){
echo(mt_rand(0,255));
}
trand();
?>
<style>
body {
    background-color:rgb(<?php trand(); ?>, <?php trand(); ?>, <?php trand(); ?>);}
h1{
    color:rgb(<?php trand(); ?>, <?php trand(); ?>, <?php trand(); ?>)}
</style>
</head>
<h1>
Random color picker
</h1>````
`````

Comment: View source code on browser and search `style` contents.

Comment: Emm  Maybe I can somehow ask browser to show me this in page?

Comment: If you're asking about how to see the final output from the above code, just right click on an empty spot on the page and click "View source". If that's not what you're asking about, then you need to clarify your question.